# WPF Find label using FindName() c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to find a label by string by it only seems to return null. From everything I've read and using the same code on a Textbox it should work but I can't figure out why it can't find my labels. My code is below

C#

```
Label lbl;

        for (int n = 1; n <= 12; n++)
        {
            lbl = (Label)FindName($"f{n}");
            lbl.Content = $"{samplingRate / 2 / n}kHz";
        }
```

and xaml

```
<Label x:Name="f1" Content="2kHz" Canvas.Left="191" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f2" Content="4kHz" Canvas.Left="298" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f3" Content="6kHz" Canvas.Left="403" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f4" Content="8kHz" Canvas.Left="508" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f5" Content="10kHz" Canvas.Left="613" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f6" Content="12kHz" Canvas.Left="718" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f7" Content="14kHz" Canvas.Left="824" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f8" Content="16kHz" Canvas.Left="929" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f9" Content="18kHz" Canvas.Left="1034" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f10" Content="20kHz" Canvas.Left="1139" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f11" Content="22kHz" Canvas.Left="1244" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="f12" Content="24kHz" Canvas.Left="1344" Canvas.Top="795" Width="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

The code breaks straight away at f1, lbl = null.

It's probably something stupid I've missed but I think I've been looking at the problem for too long, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do with `lbl.Content = $"{samplingRate / 2 / n}kHz";`?

Comment: Change the label's content based on the sum in the curly brackets, the issue is that lbl is null

Comment: I tried it and lbl wasn't null. The first line works as expected it's probably the second line. Could you show what type of result you're expecting it could help understand.

Comment: Wow, that's weird, played around a bit and it doesn't seem to be able recognise any of the labels, even if I refer to them directly, with any content string change

Comment: Try to clean your project and build.

Comment: Still doesn't like it, I'll keep playing, thanks for your advice

Comment: Where are you attempting to get the label by name, in the constructor?

Comment: The C# is in a function in the main window

Comment: And where are you calling that function.

Comment: You code works for me. I put it in a MouseUp handler

Comment: Not a solution, just a tip, using item templates, data binding and the mvvm design is the more natural way to go working with WPF. hard coding the absolute label positions, alignments etc can make resizing and scaling ineffective.

Comment: This really should be done with Bindings...

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to access the labels before the call to InitializeComponent, they'll be null.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
   public MainWindow()
   {
     // attempting to find elements
     // before the call to InitializeComponent();
     // results in null references

     // this won't work.
      WorkWithLabels();

     InitializeComponent();
     this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
   }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // this works.
      WorkWithLabels();
    }

    private void StackPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      // so does this.
      WorkWithLabels();
    }

    private void WorkWithLabels()
    {
      Label lbl;
      var samplingRate = 1.5;
      for (int n = 1; n <= 12; n++)
      {
        lbl = (Label)FindName($"f{n}");
        lbl.Content = $"{samplingRate / 2 / n}kHz";
      }
    }
  }
```